# Wrapping a C code program into R: alternatives to Rcpp?

Tags: mysql, c, r, rcpp

I have a package written entirely in C, which creates a mySQL table and executes queries.

Given that R is written in C, are there alternatives to using Rcpp to write wrappers around this C code to construct an R package? Or is Rcpp the best method available (or only method available) to do this?

Comment: Of course you can call C functions from R, take a look at this tutorial: http://users.stat.umn.edu/~geyer/rc/

Comment: And _many_ of CRAN packages using Rcpp do just thank, including some of the db connection packages such as RMariaDB (the updated RMySQL client).

Comment: And besides the Geyer tutorial, the _official manual_ describes the C API.  You can of course use that approach, but it will likely not lead to shorter code.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel "And many of CRAN packages using Rcpp do just thank" I don't understand----is this a typo?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Are there any limitations to using Rcpp to create an R package from C code? The tasks involved in this project include creating a SQL index, passing data via R to do a query via the C code. I think I would have to re-write much of the C code to work with R

Comment: No you don't to rewrite anything.  Also remember that R itself is a C program / library.

Comment: Rcpp makes it too easy not to use it. You won't need to rewrite anything as long as you did the C well. Tons of examples, too. I write wrappers to C[++] things all the time. Never had to modify the C functions I call. Ever. (well, apart from removing forbidden calls to output & error devices or 'stop'-ish things which you can't use anyway if you want it on CRAN).

Comment: And as we keep telling you: 1200+ examples on CRAN.  Study some.  Or show us concrete code to help you with.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel RMariaDB is a great example. I'm having difficulty finding on CRAN examples of Rcpp whereby there was a working C package, and they wrapped this up into an R package using Rcpp. Rather than ask you for examples....how does one find this on CRAN? (I apologise if this is a ridiculous question but...I haven't been able to figure it out)

Comment: Mastery of GitHub searching may help. I think I have a few, as does Jeroen.  But your problem still is that you _seem to not realize that `.Call()` is a C interface_ so every friggin package using it uses a C interface.  It does not matter whether your client code is C or C++.  Rcpp is still a free option for you to build interfaces to/from.  Which you can use, or ignore.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thank you. I think I now understand that `.Call()` is a C interface that provides access to R objects at the C level. For the R package, I'll put my *c package into `src/`, and include the header files `#include <R.h>` and` #include <Rinternals.h>` in each *.c file. What isn't clear yet, is that when this R package is downloaded, the C library (and the dependencies of this C library, i.e. other C libraries) must be compiled. It appears Rcpp handles this via `compileAttributes()`?

Comment: Please please PLEASE read _Writing R Extensions_.  Please do not expect me to your free on-demand tutor.  If you want Rcpp, we have written a lot documentation in the nine years we worked on it too.   Over and out.  Please do some reading.

Answer (score 2):

For backward compatibility to S lang, you may find "useful" learn something about:

`.C()`
`.Call()`

Rcpp is nowadays the most modern, performant and closest option to reuse your existing code.

Comment: The `.C()` interface is discouraged by everybody, see consensus discussions on `r-devel` in the last few years.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for anything to call C code from R, and this is documented in Writing R Extensions. So if you want to avoid using Rcpp for some reason (and I can think of a few), you can just use the R C api. It typically requires more work and more care.

There are many packages on CRAN that use C or C++ without Rcpp, [purrr](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr) comes to mind as an example.

Comment: Thanks to `tools::CRAN_package_db()` we now easily see what percentage of packages actually have `src/` directory, and then see what percentage of those opt to use Rcpp or not (forgetting for a second we also include Java and Fortran here).  When I last did that, the percentage was in the high 30%, but it has been growing steadily.  So yes, the majority of packages using compiled code do _not_ use Rcpp (yet).  But if we looked at _newer_ packages I suspect it would be more than half of those.

Comment: "if you want to avoid using Rcpp for some reason (and I can think of a few)" What reasons come to mind?